# Can't create file in directory - Java

Tags: java, hashmap, save, try-catch, fileoutputstream

I want to save all elements of a `HashMap` in a file. To do this I wrote following code with the help of some google searches:

```
 public void saveCalendars() {
        
        try {FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(CALENDARPATH_STRING);
                 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                for(Calendar elementCalendar : calendarRegister.values()) {
                    oos.writeObject(elementCalendar);
                }
                 oos.close();
                 fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            try {FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(CALENDARPATH_STRING));
                     ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                    for(Calendar elementCalendar : calendarRegister.values()) {
                        oos.writeObject(elementCalendar);
                    }
                     oos.close();
                     fos.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Creating: Error initializing stream");
                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Save: Error initializing stream");
            }

    }
```

With `final static String CALENDARPATH_STRING = "C:\\Windows\\calendars.dat";`.
I thought that I simply could use the same Code but with `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(CALENDARPATH_STRING));` if the file hasn't been created yet to create one.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It's the firs time, that a make such saving stuff, so maybe you can help me.

Comment: Could you please clarify, what "doesn't work"? Are you getting exception? Or file wasn't created?

Comment: Part of the problem is that your code does not display the error that it has been given.  Those IOExceptions likely contain an error message saying why the IO failed.  Print the messages!  You can use ex.getMessage() to get the string from the exception.

Comment: @IvanBabanin I get "File not found" and IOException

Comment: @user13784117 thank you! It says that I have no access.. That's the problem! But I've tried several other locations. everywhere the same..

Comment: You can't create files in C:\Windows - the directory is specifically protected against that, otherwise it's a security hole.   I suggest you start by trying to create a file in your home directory, likely C:\Users\<yournamehere>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Use `File.createNewFile` to create a new file and verify it's result
2. Use `try-with-resources` when dealing with IO stuff (I assume you use > JDK 7). You can read more about this feature on [official site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

You can avoid duplications:

```java
    File calendarFile = new File(CALENDARPATH_STRING);
    try {
        if(calendarFile.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("File not found. New file was created");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.printf("Can not create file %s\n", CALENDARPATH_STRING);
    }

    try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(calendarFile);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
        for(Calendar elementCalendar : calendarRegister.values()) {
            oos.writeObject(elementCalendar);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Save: Error initializing stream");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, code looks definitely better now but it's still an IOException: Can not create file C:\Windows\calendars.dat

Comment: @benicamera, I believe this is because Windows operating system prohibits to write file inside `C:\Windows\` folder. Have you try a different folder?

Comment: @benicamera, or you can run you Java program as Administrator, but I would recommend not to do that.

Comment: I've tried, but it says that I have no access. Do you know which folders are free?

Comment: @benicamera, could you please create a new folder in your C drive, for example, `calendars`.  Then update your constant to new value: 
`final static String CALENDARPATH_STRING = "C:\\calendars\\calendars.dat";` and try one more time.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot! Unfortunately I ran into the next problem xD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216823/discussion-between-benicamera-and-ivan-babanin).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can see that there is an issue with the path of your file `CALENDAR_PATH_STRING`

and use `new File(CALENDAR_PATH_STRING)` it would create a new file if the particular file was not found. Also in local I can see it is working.

```
   public void saveCalendars(Map<String, Calendar> calendarRegister) {

     try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(CALENDAR_PATH_STRING)); 
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
        for (Calendar elementCalendar : calendarRegister.values()) {
            oos.writeObject(elementCalendar);
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Creating: Error initializing stream");
      }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it would work.. I tested that in my local with two different places.. try going via windows explorer and make sure you have permission to create a file over there @benicamera

Comment: Also you cannot create any files in Windows dir, try something in Desktop or any other drives to start with @benicamera

Comment: Does not work for me.. tested several locations without success... @Sabareesh Muralidharan

Comment: Can you say your options?? @benicamera

Comment: which options do you mean?

Comment: @benicamera The file names (with extensions) you used